# Generate sets by union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am interested in finding a way to get all possible $3$-element sets that can be obtained by a certain set of sets formed by $1$-element sets and $2$-element sets.

I tried same question regarding $2$-element sets using $1$-element ones as base and got  binomial coefficients $n$ over $2$, where $n$ are amount of $1$-element sets. Also other $k$-elements generated by $1$-element ones are binomial coefficients.

But when $2$-element sets are introduced additional information on them is necessary to get a closed formula, but which is this additional info?

Without loss of generality and for simplicity reasons I assumed all sets were different at least by $1$ element.

Also appreciate if there is an easy way to get some literature on union generated sets, perhaps an specific tag would help.

For instance:

$\langle\{\{1\},\{2\},\{6\},\{3,4\},\{3,5\}\}\rangle_3 = \{\{1,2,6\},\{1,3,4\},\{1,3,5\},\{2,3,4\},\{2,3,5\},\{3,4,6\},\{3,5,6\},\{3,4,5\}\}$

Thanks in advance.

Marc

Comment: I would try first to find a formula when all the elements from all the sets are different..

Comment: And then when they are not it seems that some inclusion-exclusion principle should help.

Comment: I think it will be difficult enough if the given set of sets consists only of $2$-element sets. In other words, given a graph $G=(V,E)$, find all the induced subgraphs of $G$ which are isomorphic either to $K_{1,2}$ or to $K_3$.